# In ASP.net Page life cycle on which state Controls is accessible?

Tags: asp.net

In an ASP.net page life cycle, on which state are controls accessible?
According to me it is after Initialize, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct.

This is from MSDN:

> Init - Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin settings have been applied. 
>   The Init event of individual controls occurs before the Init event of the page.
>   Use this event to read or initialize control properties.

You may check this link for more details: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by accessible. You will usually want to access the controls sometime between OnInit and OnLoad.

Here's a great guide that explains the page lifecylce, and when to use each event:

http://www.altafkhatri.com/Technical/ASP_NET_Page_Life_Cycle_And_Events/Common_ASP_NET/Page_Events

Answer (score 0):

Initialization, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx